# How to add an onclick callback for button on every row of a DataTables table

Tags: javascript, datatables, onclick

I have a table where each row has a button. I format the table using JS [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). I'd like to add an onclick callback to the button on each row.

Right now, I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".btn-email").click(send_email);
     $(".btn-fix").click(toggle_status);
});
```

However, this only adds the onclick callback to the buttons of the rows that are shown, i.e. when navigating to a new page of the table (since DataTables handles pagination), the buttons don't work.

I've tried the following without luck:

```
$("#jfTable").on( 'draw', function () {
    $(".btn-email").click(send_email);
    $(".btn-fix").click(toggle_status);
} );
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope something like this will help you because it did work for my case.

- You could add columns property, and on each column you could map your data object by name.
- You have access to whole data from object called "dataObject"
- So here I'm creating a link with an id from other column (dataObject.id). U could create function for button, and use it with OnClick event in button properties.

See my code:

```js
{
columns: [{
          data: "name",
          render: function(data, type, dataObject, meta) {
            return `<a class="col" id="${dataObject.id}">${data}</a>`;
          }
         }]     
}
    
$(document.body).on("click", ".col", function(item) {
  console.log(item)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I settled on something a bit simpler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#jfTable').on('page.dt search.dt length.dt', function () {
    $(".btn-email").off("click").on("click", send_email);
    $(".btn-fix").off("click").on("click", toggle_status);
  });
});
```

[`page.dt`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/page), [`search.dt`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/search), or [`length.dt`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/length) are fired when the datatable view is updated in the corresponding way. `.off("click")` avoids having a button with having multiple, identical click events attached (e.g. from a previous pagination).